# Conceptual model vs Logical model vs Physical model

Tags: database-design, database-recommendation

I'm doing a work about database, and now I need to show three different images, one image with the conceptual model, other with logical model and other with physical model of a database.

I'm looking for reliable information about this, but I find different answers and I'm a bit confused.

So I came here to see if you can help me.

I have below my three images, do you think I have the correct title for each image?

**Conceptual model:**

In conceptual model, I think that I neeed to put my tables with atributes but without relationships.

[image]

**Logical Model:**

In logical model, I think I need to put my tables with  atributes, but now with my relationships.

[image]

**Physical Model:**

In physical model, I think I need to put my tables with  atributes, but now with my relationships and also with foreign keys.

[image]

Comment: I don't think you're on the right track, exactly, especially with the conceptual model.  See this answer for something which holds up pretty well, I think: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279089/what-is-the-difference-between-logical-data-model-and-conceptual-data-model

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. In that link one user recommends to see this site: http: //www.1keydata.com/datawarehousing/data-modeling-levels.html. And this site seems to have good information. Based on this site, the conceptual model have only the entities/tables and the relations between them, the logical model already has tables, relations between
 tables and attributes of each table. The physical model already has tables, relations, attributes but also
 the type and size of the fields.

Comment: But on wikipedia I saw they make reference to the physical mode as if it were the code that will be interpreted interpreted by the management system database. Like for example: CREATE TABLE products (
Product_no Text (1) PRIMARY KEY, ....) ...

Comment: What you're referring to on the Wikipedia page is the DDL (data definition language) that defines the physical schema in minute detail.  DDL is one way to express the physical model - probably a very good way, since it is very precise.  However, it is not the only way.  You can express a physical model graphically, for instance.